# Converting integer to array

Tags: c

So far I have written a few lines to convert an integer to an array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int num = 9214;
    int count = 3;
    char numarray[3];
    int temp;

    while(num > 0){
        temp = num % 10;
        numarray[count] = temp;
        num /= 10;
        count--;
    }

    printf("Array: ");
    for(count = 0; count <= 3; count++)
    printf("%d", numarray[count]);
    printf("\n\n");
}
```

The output *should* be 9214. However, it returns as 9219.
If I change the variable *num* 5183, it would return as 5185.
It changes the last number of the array to the first number of the *num* variable.

Does anyone have any idea where I've messed up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char numarray[3];
```

This array has 3 elements, not 4.

```
for(count = 0; count <= 3; count++)
    printf("%d", numarray[count]);
```

The `printf` statement accesses an element outside of the array (`numarray[3]` but the last element is `numarray[2]`). Same for `numarray[count] = temp;` in the `while` loop.

To fix your issue, just change `char numarray[3];` to `char numarray[4];`.

Comment: I feel a little stupid as I tried increasing the size of almost everything by one apart from this. Can I ask why it turned the last digit to the first in the variable?

Comment: Try more example before concluding that it is turning the last digit to the first in the variable. You are getting out of bound.

Answer (score 0):

numarray is too small.

It should be

```
char numarray[4];
```

Your while loop is overwriting memory outside of the array and your printf for loop is looking at memory outside of the array.

Comment: My original thoughts were that because I had four numbers, I only needed numarray[3] as it counts from 0. Is it 4 because of the need for the null terminator?

Comment: No, it's 4 because you have 4 numbers.  The indices are 0-3, which gives you 4 indices.

Answer (score 0):

The number has 4 digits but you are allocatting an array of size 3. The assignment to `numarray[3]` is invalid as well as using that expression for accessing the value since it is undefined behavior.

When you declare an array the number between square brackets specifies the maximum number of elements that the array can hold and *not* the value for the maximum index. Access is zero based so the possible index values in an `int nums[4];` array are 0, 1, 2 and 3.

In general for any array of `type arr[n]`, where `type` is a valid type and `n` is a literal number, valid index values go from `0` to `n - 1`.